# Лас-Вегасівський алгоритм, алгоритм "Лас-Вегас", алгоритм типу "Лас-Вегас" чи ще якось?

Tags: велика-мала-літера

Як правильно писати:

- Лас-Вегасівський алгоритм,
- алгоритм "Лас-Вегас",
- алгоритм типу "Лас-Вегас"

чи ще якось?

З лапками чи без?

[На вікі не знайшов.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Прикметникові варіанти

Прикметник пишеться так — **лас-вегаський**:

1. Літери *л* і *в* мають бути малі:

   - Сам по собі прикметник пишеться малими літерами ([§ 154.3.5 «Українського правопису» 2019 року](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=159) наводить приклади: *булóнь-сюрмéрський*, *бург-ель-арáбський* тощо).
   - Теоретично з великої могло б писатися все словосполучення (як-от *Такий-то алгоритм* чи *Алгоритм такий-то*), але я не спостерігаю традиції робити так для алгоритмів, теорем, аксіом тощо.
2. На практиці з варіантів *лас-вегаський*, *лас-вегасський*, *лас-вегасівський* найчастіше вживається перший. Наразі не можу це аргументувати. Можливо, цей варіант є в словниках (поки що бачу [лише в «ВЕСУМ»](https://r2u.org.ua/vesum/?w=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9); слід подивитися пізніше в «Словниках України онлайн», коли вони запрацюють).

Я не виключаю застосування лапок, як-от **«лас-вегаський» алгоритм** або *так званий «лас-вегаський» алгоритм*. Цим ми можемо підкреслювати, що цей алгоритм насправді не є характерним для Лас-Вегасу чи винайденим у Лас-Вегасі, а це лише умовна назва. Утім я не знаю, наскільки це обов'язково.

Прикметникові варіанти можна застосовувати і коли мова про конкретний алгоритм, і коли мова про тип/родину алгоритмів. Якщо ми хочемо підкреслити, що мова саме про тип/родину алгоритмів, то можна (але необов'язково) написати *алгоритм лас-вегаського типу* чи *алгоритм «лас-вегаського» типу*.

#### Іменникові варіанти

Є прецедент: *алгоритм Монте-Карло* чи *метод Монте-Карло*. Хоча я не знаю, у якому відмінку стоїть слово *Монте-Карло*, можливо, це родовий відмінок, як *алгоритм Лас-Вегасу* (чи *алгоритм Лас-Вегаса*), а не як *алгоритм Лас-Вегас*.

Цей прецедент не беззаперечний. Цілком може бути, що це радше усталений виняток, аніж характерий випадок. Але на практиці, мені здається, **якщо не вийде чітких і суворих настанов, що треба писати по-іншому**, то де-факто всі писатимуть *алгоритм Лас-Вегас* (або з прикметником).

#### Прислівникові варіанти

Радше для гумору — *алгоритм по-ласвегаськи*:

1. Тут дефіс між «лас» і «вегас» не треба через [примітку 1 у § 41.3.1 «Українського правопису» 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=46) («У прислівниках такого зразка, утворених від складних прикметників, що їх пишемо з дефісом, дефіс ставимо тільки після *по-*: *по-соціалдемократи́чному*, *по-генералгубернáторському»*).
2. Щодо лапок питання відкрите.